# no focus for key events in swt

Tags: java, swt, rcp, keyevent

I'm currently having problems with SWT `KeyEvent`s. In an RCP application I have several controls that will be focused if you are tabbing through, e.g. first toolbar icon, another one, finally the editor and a class which is in the editor (a composite, it'll be focused as well).

This particular class receives key events; only - of course - if it is focused and I need to process these events (remember this class gets focus *after* the editor was focused because the editor holds an instance)

Is there any way to guarantee that this composite will have focus if for example the mouse is over this area?

Already tried to solve this with `MouseEvent`s but even then `setFocus()` does not always provide focus (same goes for `forceFocus()`).

Comment: Keyboard focus has nothing to do with the location of the mouse, except if you are using a native OS-level configuration that sets keyboard focus that way.

Comment: Could you update the question with what you are trying to do?  Eclipse RCP comes with a command/keybinding infrastructure that allows key shortcuts to work as long as the window has focus.